# Selecting the first flash message in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, flash-message

I only want to grab the first flash message. I have to send this message to an object. So far I have

```
flash.first.last if flash.present? and flash.first.present?
```

In some cases the flash doesn't exist at all so I have to first check that it exists, then see if it has a message. I honestly don't like it. Does the FlashHash or Rails have a method that does this behavior out-of-the-box? Is there a cleaner way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to shorten it, you can use safe navigation:

```
flash.try(:first).try(:last) # Ruby < 2.3
flash&.first&.last           # Ruby >= 2.3
```

For list of flash hash methods refer to [`ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html) documentation.

Comment: I don't know how I feel about using the `try` method. It had crossed my mind. I'll think about it some more. Thanks.

Comment: @jason328 I don't really understand what your expected behaviour is. Documentation is there, and it definitely does not have `.first.last` functionality out of the box :)

Comment: No you're right. I was just hopeful for something more. C'est la vie.